# Session timeout different for group of users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session-timeout, state-management

Is it Possible to set Session timeout different for different users in asp.net.

i have session setting in my web.config like.

```
<system.web>
 <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="80" />
</system.web>
```

but i want to time out it before 80 .

Answer (score 2):

example:

```
protected void SetSessionTime(string user)
{
    if (user== "me")
    {
        Session.Timeout = 180;
    }
    else
    {
        Session.Timeout = 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the users timeout after they are logged in, e.g.

```
Session.Timeout = 42;
```